# Tensorflow Unsupported feed type

Tags: tensorflow

Hoping someone can help me out with this TensorFlow (1.3) error when attempting to do a WideAndDeep model. At the limits of my sanity.

**Error:**
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unsupported feed type

**Full Stack:**

```
2017-11-09 00:42:06.024911: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:00:1e.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.10GiB
2017-11-09 00:42:06.024939: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1055] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:1e.0, compute capability: 3.7)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1300, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 89, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 467, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
c_api.TF_GetCode(status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unsupported feed type 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "BareBonesWideDeep.py", line 152, in <module>
train_and_eval('', 'wide_n_deep', 50,'', '')
File "BareBonesWideDeep.py", line 129, in train_and_eval
m.train(input_fn=input_fn(train_file_name, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True), steps=train_steps)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 255, in train
loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 717, in _train_model
_, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 537, in __exit__
self._close_internal(exception_type)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 574, in _close_internal
self._sess.close()
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 820, in close
self._sess.close()
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 941, in close
ignore_live_threads=True)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py", line 94, in _run
sess.run(enqueue_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 889, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1118, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1315, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
File "/home/centos/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Unsupported feed type
```

The only thing I've seen from searching is this code where it looks like
it is from Tensorflow and is doing data mapping from python to TF internal and throws "Unsupported feed type". 
https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/python/client/tf_session_helper.cc

Printing my feature data types results in:

```
f_1     float64
f_2     float64
f_3     float64
f_4     float64
f_5     float64
f_6     float64
f_7     float64
f_8     float64
f_9     float64
f_10    float64
f_11    float64
f_12     object
f_13    float64
```

The last of my code in the stack trace is m.train where it invokes the input_fcn:

```
print("Training.....")
print('num_epochs train_and_eval:' + str(train_steps))
m.train(input_fn=input_fn(train_file_name, num_epochs=None, 
shuffle=True), steps=train_steps)

def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle):
    """Input builder function."""
    df_data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df_data.fillna(0, inplace = True)
    df_data = df_data[df_data['y_actual_bucket']>=-4]
    df_data.f_12 = df_data.f_12.astype(str)
    df_data['f_12'] = 'a'
    print("CSV file data dimensions:",df_data.shape)
    print('num_epochs input_fn:' + str(num_epochs))
    labels = df_data["y_actual_bucket"]#.apply(lambda x: ">50K" in x).astype(int)
    labels = labels+4
    df_data = df_data.iloc[:,5:]
    train_test_cutoff = int(df_data.shape[0]*.7)
    if data_file == 'fake1':
      df_data = df_data.iloc[:train_test_cutoff,:]
      labels = labels.iloc[:train_test_cutoff]
      print("Training data shape:", df_data.shape)
    else:
      df_data = df_data.iloc[train_test_cutoff:,:]
      labels = labels.iloc[train_test_cutoff:]
      print("test data shape:", df_data.shape)  
    print(df_data.dtypes)
    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=df_data,
        y=labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        num_threads=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very irritating and unhelpful error message. I solved it by coercing my features and labels to `float32`:

`df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.astype('float32'))`

I believe this error arises because `tf.feature_column.numeric_column()` defaults to `float32`.